# How can I tell if a WalletOperation failed in Taquito?

Tags: rpc, taquito

How can I tell if a WalletOperation failed in Taquito?

After I dispatch a WalletOperation, I can await the results using [the confirmation method](https://tezostaquito.io/typedoc/classes/_taquito_taquito.walletoperation.html#confirmation) like so:

```
const confirmation = await op.confirmation()
```

However, I'm not sure how to tell if the operation was successfully included in the blockchain. The value `confirmation.completed` and the function `confirmation.isInCurrentBlock` have `true` values even when the operation fails.
Is this a bug or am I using the API incorrectly?

Thanks!

Clarification: I'm looking for something like tzkt.io's [`/v1/operations/{hash}`](https://api.tzkt.io/#operation/Operations_GetByHash), which returns an object with a `status` field that has values like "applied" or "failed".
But I'd rather not rely on an external service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After calling the `confirmation` method, the `status` method can be called on the `WalletOperation` object.

For example:

```
const operation = await Tezos.wallet.originate({...}).send();
await operation.confirmation();
const status = await operation.status();
```

The status can have the following value: `'applied' | 'failed' | 'skipped' | 'backtracked'`

Comment: There isn't a `status` member on the WalletOperation object. See https://imgur.com/a/8ZPu06G

Comment: Thanks Roxane for pointing out this bug on Telegram: https://github.com/ecadlabs/taquito/issues/962. It looks like it'll be fixed for batch operations soon